# How to correctly replace scalars with matrices?

Tags: matrix, replacement

How can a scalar be replaced with a matrix to perform operations on the matrix, not its elements?

For example,

```
A = RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}]
Sin[x] /. x -> A
```

returns something like

```
{{Sin[1], Sin[1], Sin[1], -Sin[1]}, 
{-Sin[1], -Sin[1], Sin[1], 0}, 
{0, -Sin[1], -Sin[1], 0}, 
{-Sin[1], Sin[1], -Sin[1], Sin[1]}}
```

instead of matrix sine.

Comment: Functions of matrices are tricky beasts, as usually ones needs the eigensystem of the matrix etc. Thus, I don't think this question is well posed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"MatrixFunction" will do what you want. Here is an example with "Sqrt":

```
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}];
sq = MatrixFunction[Sqrt, a];

Chop[sq . sq - a]

{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

I used "Chop" because of numerical errors due to machine precision.

Comment: Also `MatrixPower[sq, 2] - a // Chop`

Comment: Does it work with user-defined things? Will something like `MatrixFunction[Sin/2 + Sqrt + 1, a]` work?

Comment: @homocomputeris For that, you'll need to define a pure function: `MatrixFunction[Sin[#]/2 + Sqrt[#] + 1 &, a]`.